# Why array is not showing proper result in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, sorting

Below is the screen of my VScode, I am declaring arr1 as an array of numbers and later reversing it.[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRiQV.jpg)

The problem is that on output the 1st paragraph is showing the reversed arrays instead of original one. What is the exact problem?
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QwYf.jpg)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: in the documentation they say `Careful: reverse is destructive -- it changes the original array.`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let reverse = Array.from(arr1).reverse()
```

As reverse() method modifies the original array (arr1), then you need to create a new array with Array.from(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Answer (score 0):

Reverse is a mutating method, so both `arr1` and `reverse` reference the same array. You'll want to do something like `const reverse = [...arr1].reverse()` instead to ensure that you aren't mutating the original array.